# How do I write a batch file to open files in a folder

Tags: file, loops

I am trying to create a batch file whereby it opens files from the start to the end of the folder. At the same time, it needs to save it as a different file type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "folder path"
```

Or

```
START "FolderPath"
```

Without Quotes